# Create a simple widget

Tags: widgets

I wanna create a simple widget that show an image and text with a link.
Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aF4UR/

But I want to include this as a widget with fields.

For example in the back end:

Image: [insert image url here]
Image Link [link]
Title:[title here]
Title link: [insert link here]
Text:[text field]

And in the front end display as the code in jsfiddle.

Any help?

Comment: Ans what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/how-create-widget-wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct question would be "how to create a widget"?  No code was initiated. I recommend reading this tutorial: [Building Custom Wordpress Widgets](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/building-custom-wordpress-widgets/)

Anyway... your widget:

```
class widget_simple extends WP_Widget {

    // Create Widget
    function widget_simple() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Custom Simple Widget', array('description' => ''));
    }

    // Widget Content
    function widget($args, $instance) { 
        extract( $args );
        $simple_image_url = strip_tags($instance['simple_image_url']);
        $simple_image_link = strip_tags($instance['simple_image_link']);
        $simple_title = strip_tags($instance['simple_title']);
        $simple_title_link = strip_tags($instance['simple_title_link']);
        $simple_text = strip_tags($instance['simple_text']);

        ?>

            <div id="latest-box">

                <span class="img-box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $simple_image_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $simple_image_url; ?>"></a>
                </span> <!-- img-box -->

                <span class="latest-title">
                    <a href="<?php echo $simple_title_link; ?>"><?php echo $simple_title; ?></a>
                </span> <!-- title -->

                <span class="latest-text">
                    <?php echo $simple_text; ?>
                </span> <!-- text -->

            </div> <!-- box -->

        <?php
     }

    // Update and save the widget
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        return $new_instance;
    }

    // If widget content needs a form
    function form($instance) {
        //widgetform in backend
        $simple_image_url = strip_tags($instance['simple_image_url']);
        $simple_image_link = strip_tags($instance['simple_image_link']);
        $simple_title = strip_tags($instance['simple_title']);
        $simple_title_link = strip_tags($instance['simple_title_link']);
        $simple_text = strip_tags($instance['simple_text']);
        ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_image_url'); ?>">Image URL: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_image_url'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('simple_image_url'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($simple_image_url); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_image_link'); ?>">Image Link: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_image_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('simple_image_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($simple_image_link); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_title'); ?>">Title: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('simple_title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($simple_title); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_title_link'); ?>">Title Link: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_title_link'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('simple_title_link'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($simple_title_link); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_text'); ?>">Text: </label>
                <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('simple_text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('simple_text'); ?>"><?php echo attribute_escape($simple_text); ?></textarea>
            </p>

        <?php       
    }

}

register_widget('widget_simple');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!
(another quick one, how can I call the tinyMCE in the text fields?)

Comment: TinyMCE is related to TinyMCE. Just download the basic TinyMCE package then see how it works. Usually you need to call TinyMCE js file and add a textarea with a particular id or name. Basically, TinyMCE modifies the content of that area, including the icons/bar/content drawing, all in the same textarea content.